# What is the maximum number of iterations before a sequence is repeated

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations

$A = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$

$B = \{f,g,h\}$

$C = \{i,j\}$

$D = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

Suppose a four-tuple is constructed by extracting one element from each set at each successive iteration. The stipulation is that these elements must be accessed sequentially, so the first few iterations will always result in the following tuples:

$1.$ $(a,f,i,0)$

$2.$ $(b,g,j,1)$

$3.$ $(c,h,i,2)$

$4.$ $(d,f,j,3)$

$...$

I'm trying to determine what is the maximum number of iterations such that no four-tuple is repeated. So if we have $(a,f,i,0)$ as the first iteration, and this exactly tuple is repeated in iteration $100$ (and none of the other tuples in the list are repeated) then the answer is 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use modular calculus to find the first positive integer which satisfies:
$$n\equiv 0\mod(5);\  n\equiv 0\mod(3); \  n\equiv 0 \mod(2);\ n\equiv 0 \mod(7)$$

which in fact returns the least common multiple:

$$5\cdot3\cdot2\cdot7=210$$

Comment: How did you come to $5\times 3 \times 2 \times 7$?

Comment: Since the four integers in this case are all relatively prime their least common multiple is simply the multiplication of the four. Otherwise go with prime factorisation to find the $LCM$

Comment: So if we had $5,3,2,20$ we would do $5 \times 3 \times 2 \times (2 \times 2 \times 5)$?

Comment: No. Since $20=2\times2\times5$ The least common multiple becomes: $5\times2\times2\times3=60$
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Least_common_multiple#Finding_least_common_multiples_by_prime_factorization

Comment: May I suggest the formulation *first positive integer* $n$:  $$ n \equiv 0 \pmod{5}\; ; n \equiv 0 \pmod{3}\; ; n \equiv 0 \pmod{2}\; ; n \equiv 0 \pmod{7} $$

Comment: Absolutely! I'll edit straight away.